# Android AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for session 35305, record source 1, initialization check failed with status -22

Tags: android, audiorecord

I am trying to use the `AudioRecord` object but I am not able to successfully record voice.
I checked the similar questions and made sure to apply their recommendations but still got the same error.
I added needed permissions to the manifest file, and because I am my devce runs Android M, I added the following code as per the suggestions I skimmed through but it still didn't help:

```
private void requestRecordAudioPermission() {
        //check API version, do nothing if API version < 23!
        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // Should we show an explanation?
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {

                    // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                } else {

                    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    Log.d("Activity", "Granted!");

                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Log.d("Activity", "Denied!");
                    finish();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
```

Here is the error and logs I get:

```
    Could not get audio input for session 35305, record source 1, sample rate 48000, format 0x1, channel mask 0x10, flags 0
   E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -22.
   E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
    I/myRecordThread.Run: Successfully created new AudioRecord
    I/myRecordThread.Run: AudioRecord NOT_INITIALIZED
    I/myRecordThread.Run: Released AudioRecord
```

And here is the code:
This is how I create the record thread:

```
    public myRecordThread() {
    audioQuality = 60000;

    //get teh maximum possible recording sample rate
    for (final int s : new int[] { 48000, 44100, 22050, 11025, 8000 }) {
        bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(
                s,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        if (bufferSize > 0) {
            recordingSampleRate = s;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (bufferSize < 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No recording sample rate found");
    }

    Log.i("mumbleclient", "Selected recording sample rate: " +
            recordingSampleRate);

    frameSize = recordingSampleRate / 100;

    buffer = new short[frameSize];
    celtMode = Native.celt_mode_create(
            MumbleProtocol.SAMPLE_RATE, /*48000*/
            MumbleProtocol.FRAME_SIZE); /*480*/
    celtEncoder = Native.celt_encoder_create(celtMode, 1);
    Native.celt_encoder_ctl(
            celtEncoder,
            celtConstants.CELT_SET_PREDICTION_REQUEST,
            0);
    Native.celt_encoder_ctl(
            celtEncoder,
            celtConstants.CELT_SET_VBR_RATE_REQUEST,
            audioQuality);

    if (recordingSampleRate != TARGET_SAMPLE_RATE) {
        speexResamplerState = Native.speex_resampler_init(
                1,
                recordingSampleRate,
                TARGET_SAMPLE_RATE,
                3);
    } else {
        speexResamplerState = 0;
    }
    Log.i("myRecordThread.Run", "Successfully created voiceRecord thread");
}
```

And here is the thread's run method:

```
@Override
public final void run() {
    Log.i("myRecordThread.Run", "Just Started voiceRecord Thread");
    final boolean running = true;
    android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
    Log.i("myRecordThread.Run", "Thread given Urgent Priority");
    AudioRecord ar = null;
    try {
        ar = new AudioRecord(
                MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                recordingSampleRate,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                64 * 1024);
        Log.i("myRecordThread.Run", "Successfully created new AudioRecord");

        if (ar.getState() != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
            Log.i("myRecordThread.Run", "AudioRecord NOT_INITIALIZED");
            return;
        }

        ar.startRecording();
        Log.i("myRecordThread.Run", "Started Recording...");
        while (running && !Thread.interrupted()) {
            final int read = ar.read(buffer, 0, frameSize);

            if (read == AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE ||
                    read == AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION) {
                throw new RuntimeException("" + read);
            }

            short[] out;
            if (speexResamplerState != 0) {
                out = resampleBuffer;
                final int[] in_len = new int[] { buffer.length };
                final int[] out_len = new int[] { out.length };
                Native.speex_resampler_process_int(
                        speexResamplerState,
                        0,
                        buffer,
                        in_len,
                        out,
                        out_len);
            } else {
                out = buffer;
            }

            final int compressedSize = Math.min(
                    audioQuality / (100 * 8),
                    127);
            final byte[] compressed = new byte[compressedSize];
            synchronized (Native.class) {
                Native.celt_encode(
                        celtEncoder,
                        out,
                        compressed,
                        compressedSize);
            }
            outputQueue.add(compressed);

            if (outputQueue.size() < framesPerPacket) {
                continue;
            }

            final byte[] outputBuffer = new byte[1024];
            final PacketDataStream pds = new PacketDataStream(outputBuffer);
            while (!outputQueue.isEmpty()) {
                int flags = 0;
                flags |= getCodec() << 5;
                outputBuffer[0] = (byte) flags;

                pds.rewind();
                // skip flags
                pds.next();
                seq += framesPerPacket;
                pds.writeLong(seq);
                for (int i = 0; i < framesPerPacket; ++i) {
                    final byte[] tmp = outputQueue.poll();
                    if (tmp == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    int head = (short) tmp.length;
                    if (i < framesPerPacket - 1) {
                        head |= 0x80;
                    }

                    pds.append(head);
                    pds.append(tmp);
                }

                sendUdpMessage(outputBuffer, pds.size(), false);
            }
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (ar != null) {
            ar.release();
            Log.i("myRecordThread.Run", "Released AudioRecord");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey there you got any suceess